# How can I generate dynamic images in SSRS 2008 based on the results set of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am using the following SQL query in SSRS:

```
select s.name, s.studentid, x.section_number
from students s
inner join sections x
on s.studentid=x.studentid
where section_number = :Section
```

This query produces a list of 10-20 students depending on which 'section' (class) is entered into the *:Section* parameter. In addition to this, I also want to produce a picture of each student dynamically that matches up with the list.

I have every student's picture on a webserver, and if there's just one value for student then I could use a parameter for StudentID and set the image expression as follows:

```
="http://website.com/img/" & Parameters!StudentID.Value & ".jpg"
```

However, I need to have a picture for every student that is returned in the results. Is this possible in SSRS?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is certainly possible. The problem is you need to have those pictures in the database, in order to return them in the result-set.

You can write a CLR stored procedure that goes and fetches the images, then inserts them into a table in the database. Or a stored procedure that calls a windows/web service that does that.

I have a art-report that does that:

```
SELECT 
         [...]
        ,
        ISNULL
        (
            T_File.Thumbnail 
            ,
            CAST
            (
                0xff[... default image byte-array too large for SO...]
                AS varbinary(MAX)
            ) 
        ) AS RPT_Thumbnail
    FROM T_Art
```

By the way, you can get the [image mime-type from the file's extension in SQL](http://pastebin.com/8bzXjFy7)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The only problem is, I'm querying a read-only database, so I won't be able to insert those pictures into the DB. I would be able to insert them into the report server DB, but this obviously wouldn't allow them to be in the same result set. Is there any other way, other than having the picture as a DB object?

Comment: You could create a linked server in the "read-only" database. Then you can reach over to the reportserver database from your read-only database. Then you can have them in the same result set. Just  not sure how fast that would be.

Comment: Excellent, I'll try that. Thanks for the help.